# How to change color of intersected parts of CAShapeLayer in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, graphics, cashapelayer

I am trying to draw CGPaths using CAShapeLayer. I want to change the color of the parts where lines are intersected.

Following screenshots explain the goal easier.

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/046/Purple/a3/9b/29/mzl.pocvbqdb.320x480-75.jpg

http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/037/Purple/1d/54/44/mzl.dpijulvx.320x480-75.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Check `@Alex Nichol`'s Answer on this post, [How to determine intersection of CGPaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757517/how-to-determine-intersection-of-cgpaths) .

He developed an Open Source solution to CGPath collision detection, as well as a youtube video showing it in Action.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I checked that solution and tried the code but it does not work for me. That code only returns one pixel of the intersected parts, if lines have width more than 1 pixel there is no straightforward way to change whole intersected part's color. I need something to burn colors somehow.