# How to found the intersection of two CAShapelayer

Tags: ios, calayer, cashapelayer

I am having more than one `CAShapeLayer`. 
While dragging two layers, I need to find whether it's intersecting are not.

But I tried in my way of calculating frame intersection and points intersection. But it's always returning frame as `CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)`, I mean zero for all the layers frame as well the position too getting zero.

If any one knows give some idea.

Comment: Did you try **CGRectIntersection()**?

Comment: Do you want to check whether the **layers** or in the **paths** in the layers intersect?

Comment: Do the layers have a common superlayer?

Comment: Calling `CGRectStandardize` is recommended practise if you are doing custom calculations on frames. It can happen that they have weird definitions.

Comment: Show your code and describe what exactly does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(layer1.frame, layer2.frame))
{
   /* Do something when the intersect.
}
```

I appreciate that you might want to know if the paths intersect, which is a more difficult calculation discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757517/how-to-determine-intersection-of-cgpaths)