# NSTrackingArea for custom shapes

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to create a canvas that draws diagrams.

For that I've created custom class derived from `NSView` where I've drown two rectangles and connected them with two lines.

I am using `NSView.addTrackingArea` functionality in order to move and resize rectangles.

The issue I am facing with, How to create tracking areas to track mouse events for lines? (`NSTrackingArea` accepts `NSRect` shapes.)

The second question is more about approach. How do you think, this approach is okay to manipulate with graphic objects?

[image]

Comment: If you really would like to use tracking areas and not some computer graphics algorithms for that, I think you should approximate your line with little rectangles. So you would potentially have for example 3x3 points areas where center of each square lands on the line.

Comment: What is the another approach? You mentioned graphics algorithms.

Comment: We studied some of them as University what was long ago... But you can try to google something. I just found something on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692922/check-is-a-point-x-y-is-between-two-points-drawn-on-a-straight-line

Comment: this could be an answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482362/hit-detection-when-drawing-lines-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the approach you outline in your question is appropriate. As you've seen already tracking areas can't represent non-rectangular shapes, and if you're creating a graphics app you're going to need to represent a variety of shapes that aren't rectangular, not just lines. Fortunately help is at hand from Apple itself in the form [Sketch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html), a sample drawing app that answers some fundamental questions about the basic setup of any program that wants to draw lots of different shapes to the screen.

[image]

Here's a quick overview of how they get shapes onto the canvas and how they hit-test those shapes:

- The canvas is a single `NSView` with a single array containing `Graphic` objects.
- `Graphic` is an *abstract base class* that inherits from `NSObject`. It exposes a number of *empty* methods:

  ```
  Graphic: NSObject
      - isContentUnderPoint(point: CGPoint) -> Bool
      - frame: CGRect
      - drawInRect(rect: CGPoint)
  ```
- There are a number of concrete `Graphic` subclasses (`Line`, `Rectangle`, `Circle`, `Square`, etc), each of which implements the above methods, as required.
- Getting the shapes to the screen occurs in the canvas's `drawRect:`

  ```
  // In MyCanvas (an NSView subclass)
  func drawRect(dirtyRect: CGRect) {
      for shape in self.graphics {
          shape.drawInRect(dirtyRect) 
      }
  }
  ```
- Hit testing is much the same principle...

  ```
  // in MyCanvas (an NSView subclass)
  func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent {
      let canvasPoint = convertPoint(theEvent.locationInWindow, fromView: nil)
      for shape in self.graphics {
          if shape.isContentUnderPoint(canvasPoint) {
              // do something!
          }
      }
  }
  ```

In the case of a `Line` shape, a `isContentUnderPoint` implementation would maybe calculate the equation of the line (using its start- and end- point) and then plug in the mouse-down point to see if it *fits* the equation. All in all it would take no more than a handful of lines of code, and it completely avoids any Cocoa drawing gymnastics.

Comment: Looks like this is the answer to my second question. As for line detection, its not enough, I think. In order to hit the line you need to hit into exact point that will fit the line equation, no matter how fat the line is. I found the solution, is to build invisible NSBezierPath around the line, which is thicker than target line. And use NSBezierPath.containsPoint for hit detection.